# Add List Element As Value In Dictionary Using Loop In Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have the following dictionary :

```
numDict = {
    "1" : '0',
    "2" : '0',
    "3" : '0',
    "4" : '0',
    "5" : '0',
    "6" : '0',
    "7" : '0',
    "8" : '0',
    "9" : '0',
    "10" : '0',
    "11" : '0',
    "12" : '0',
}
```

And the following list :

```
numList = ['30', ' ', '40', '6', '40', '34', '4', '20', '5', '74', ' ','36']
```

I want to insert each element of numList as value of numDict using loop, so the value of each key in numDict should be like this :

```
numDict = {
        "1" : '30',
        "2" : ' ',
        "3" : '40',
        "4" : '6',
        "5" : '40',
        "6" : '34',
        "7" : '4',
        "8" : '20',
        "9" : '5',
        "10" : '74',
        "11" : ' ',
        "12" : '36',
    }
```

I'm confuse with the way I should insert the list element as dictionary value. Should I loop over dictionary key?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can `zip` the data to pair the keys from `numDict` and the values from `numList`

   ```
   zip(inumDict, numList)
   > [('1', '30'), ('2', ' '), ('3', '40'), ...]
   ```
2. Then create a `dict` with that mappings

   ```
   dict([('1', '30'), ('2', ' '), ('3', '40')])
   > {'1': '30', '2': ' ', '3': '40'}
   ```

---

Final code

```
inumDict = {"1": '0', "2": '0', "3": '0', "4": '0',
            "5": '0', "6": '0', "7": '0', "8": '0',
            "9": '0', "10": '0', "11": '0', "12": '0', }

numList = ['30', ' ', '40', '6', '40', '34', '4', '20', '5', '74', ' ', '36']
result = dict(zip(inumDict, numList))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate the dictionary and the list in parallel using `zip`, then assign new value to the dictionary for each key, you can use dictionary comprehension.

```py
>>> {k:newVal for k,newVal in zip(numDict, numList)}

{'1': '30', '2': ' ', '3': '40', '4': '6', '5': '40', '6': '34', '7': '4', '8': '20', '9': '5', '10': '74', '11': ' ', '12': '36'}
```